# Prove that an ideal quotient is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let R be a commutative ring with identity and I, J be ideals in R.

$I:J$ = {$r∈R\mid rj∈I, \forall j∈J$}

Prove that $I:J$ is an ideal in $R$, and contains $I$.

To begin this, I wrote $I:J$ in the form

$I:J$ = {$r∈R\mid rJ \subset I$}

Let $r_1,r_2∈ I:J$. Clearly $r_1-r_2∈R$, and $r_1J, r_2J \subset I$.
Because $I$ is a ring,

if $r_1j, r_2j∈I$, then $(r_1 - r_2)j∈I$, so that $(r_1-r_2)J \subset I$. This implies that $I:J$ is an ideal. Is this the correct line of thinking? Furthermore, I'm unsure how to prove that $I \subset I:J$ in a general manner

Answer (score 3):

You're working too hard, and your work is not quite right. You need to show two things to show that $I:J$ is an ideal; (1) $I:J$ is closed under addition and (2) $I:J$ is closed under multiplication by elements of the ring $R$.

For (1), suppose $r_{1}, r_{2} \in I:J$. Then for any $j \in J$, $(r_{1}+r_{2})j = r_{1}j + r_{2}j \in I$. This follows since $r_{1}j, r_{2}j \in I$ by hypothesis, and $I$ is an ideal, hence closed under addition.

I will leave (2) for you to try. A hint: you will again need to use the fact that $I$ is an ideal, but this time, you need to use the second property of ideals referenced above.

To see that $I \subset I:J$, remember that ideals are closed under multiplication by elements of the ring. Thus, for any $j \in J$ and any $i \in I$, we know that $ij = ji \in RI = I$.

Comment: Thank you for the help. For (2):
Let r∈R, a∈I:J, j∈J.  Then

r(aj) = (ra)j∈I:J,    because ra∈R,       and,
(aj)r = a(rj)∈I:J,    because rj∈J

Comment: @infinitylord: it's not clear to me that what you've written shows (2); think carefully about what you want to show. You want to show that if $a \in I:J$, then $ra \in I:J$. If $a \in I:J$, then $aj \in I$ for all $j \in J$. Then $raj \in I$ for all $j \in J$ because $I$ is closed under multiplication by elements of the ring.

Comment: In my class, we have to prove that the colon ideal is nonempty to prove that it's ideal. I understand how subtraction/addition and multiplication are closed, but I can't seem to think about why $I:J$ is nonempty. Any help?

Comment: @user21: $0$ is an element of every ideal of any ring; can you see how to use this?

Comment: yeah. You're just saying $0\in{R, I, J}$...so $0j$ for any $j\in{J}$ is equal to $0\in{I}$, so $0\in{I:J}$?

Comment: @user21: yep, that's right!